# how to set an app as an sms app android

Tags: android

I have developed an android app that sends sms. My problem is that when I click the text message icon for a contact, the pop up that asks you to specify which application you will like to use, does not have my app as part of the options. Can anybody help with this?

I have added an image to make the question much clearer.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/itFvN.png

This is the code for the manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.smsmessaging"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
</uses-permission>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".SMS"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>               
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".Receiver"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name=
                "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Comment: Can you post the code, where you struggled?

Comment: For sending SMS, it's a simple application.. It just include few intents to send msg.. See this link: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

Comment: Lokesh, I've already looked at that one. I installed it on my phone and I have that same problem. Whatsapp appears in the list of options but the app from that site does not.

Comment: Didn't get your problem... Can you explain briefly..

Comment: When you click on the send message icon, an alert with this title appears: "Complete action using". The alert displays a list of all messaging apps found on the phone e.g. skype, whatsapp, viber etc. My app does not appear in this list.

Comment: I have added a link to an image to help explain exactly what I'm referring to

Comment: I think, those are already installed apps in your device...But, for sending message it wont ask anything like this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do it. All I had to do was add the intent-filter bellow to the activity:

```
        <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              <data android:scheme="sms" />
              <data android:scheme="smsto" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an `<intent-filter>` for the ACTION_SEND action. This will put it in the list

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

This example is from the [Google page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.google.note" />
</intent-filter>
```

Pay attention to the data element

Comment: I added an intent with the ACTION_SEND action but I still have the same issues. I have added a copy of my manifest file and an image to explain further.

Comment: What is it that you are acutally trying to send. You need to filter by MIME type eg you may only be able to use text/plain

Comment: The problem is not about what kind of message I'm sending, I want my application to be part of the applications recognized as messaging apps on the phone.

Comment: Yes but you need to accept the type of data it is trying to send. For example Messaging may accept image/jpeg and text/plain types but might not accept application/pdf. Under the intent-filter you need to filter by data. Check updated answer

Comment: jb11, If you look at the manifest file I added, I have already set a data tag. I just need to know if there's a way for the app to be appear on the alert that displays messaging apps as displayed in the image I added. Thank you